# Restoring a corrupt ubuntu partition

Tags: hard-drive

I installed Ubuntu 15.04 in my USB external hard-disk, and have been using it for a while, then I accidentally unplugged the hard-disk. 
Now there seems to be a problem with it, because I cannot log in to my Ubuntu 15.04.

So i installed Ubuntu 14.04 in a separate partition and now i can see my files in other partition in which Ubuntu 15.04 was installed.
How do i fix this error and successfully log in to my initial 15.04?

Comment: You'll need to run a filesystem check on that partition, something like `sudo fsck /dev/sdXY`. See `man fsck` for more info.

Answer (score 1):

There is command line based good software to recover corrupt partition called [TestDisk](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/precise/testdisk/)

It once helped me to recover accidentally deleted partition table, it can also be used to recover partition or fix errors in it.

You should watch this [youtube video](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=EncqYP1ijFg) before you use it, its pretty easy to use but handle it carefully

OR

A simple method you should give a try before TestDisk
Since you can boot to 14.04 you should try this simple pre-installed command, it also can be used to fix corrupt partition and recover data

```
sudo fsck.ext4 /dev/sdaX
```

**note you have to replace X in above command with a number corresponding to the partition containing 15.04.** For this you can use a software called `Disk`. You should search for it in search dash

Answer (score 0):

Try using fsck **`/dev/sda2 -y`**

**-y** : avoid asking yes/no everytime and allow/yes for all operation.

after performing this action, you will get something like,

```
/dev/sda2: ***** FILE SYSTEM WAS MODIFIED *****
/dev/sda2: 288888/30498816 files (0.2% non-contiguous), 5519494/121965056 blocks
```

Now, reboot your system and everything should work normal.